# How can I control humidity levels when curing salami?

Tags: curing, salami

I have a problem with a fridge I am converting to a curer, namely high humidity. I have read a similar question on this forum, however my problem is slightly more complicated. I will start off by saying I live in the UK, where humidity is on the whole higher than in the States.

I am successfully controlling my temperature by turning the fridge on and off via a temperature controller, but the humidity is driving me mad.I cannot seem to get it lower than 85-80%, even with a humidity controller turning a light on to raise the temperature, so the compressor runs more frequently. This does lower the humidity, but as soon as the compressor turns off, the humidity is straight back up to 85%, and this is with no food in it.

I'm guessing that as a salami dries it will release moisture it loses into the atmosphere of the fridge, increasing the humidity.  If I open my door the humidity immediately rises to 100% every time without fail, so I figure putting any sort of vent in the side will be counter productive.  Ive got a 3kg tray of salt in the bottom which I swap daily and dry the removed tray in the oven.  I'd really appreciate any help on this.

Comment: You could get a very small dehumidifier with could work in a fridge. I have seen people use such things in cheese fridges.

Comment: Hi Neil, thanks for the suggestion, I have seen small dehumidifiers that could certainly do the job, and have not discounted the idea, I'll see how I progress with the Silica gel. Thanks so much for taking the time to make a suggestion.

Comment: This is very odd as normally it's the opposite problem you would have as in too little moisture. What temperature range are you after? I would guess your fridge is too cold

Comment: Thanks for the post Giorgos, I'm keeping the fridge at 12*C

Answer (score 3):

Instead of salt, you could get silica gel. These crystals can be found by the bucket, not just in tiny packets. They also make a variety with an indicator that turns pink when they need to be changed.  Bake to refresh them.

Silica gel is amazing stuff.  There is no way you'll not be able to keep the air dry with a mass of absorber tye same scale as the salami.   It's just a matter of how often you'll need to change it.

Comment: Thanks, for the suggestion by coincidence I had sent of for some silica gel which arrived this weekend, you are right, I had humiditiy down at 50% so I'm just playing round with ways to regulate the drying effect but it definitely seems like a doable solution.  Thanks so much for taking the time to make a suggestion.

Comment: @Baz : you might be able to put the gel in a chamber without much ventilation and then use a fan when you want to lower the humidity to pull air through the chamber.

Comment: @baz use the vote-up button if you found it helpful; we don't spell out thanks comments here on SE sites.